# How to open GStreamer pipeline in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to open *webm* video using GStreamer pipeline in OpenCV program.

I'm using OpenCV 3.4.1 in Visual Studio 19 Community IDE.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string pipeline = "playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm";
    std::cout << "Using pipeline: \n" << pipeline << "\n";

    cv::VideoCapture cap(pipeline, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open camera." << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }

    cv::namedWindow("CSI Camera", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::Mat img;

    std::cout << "Hit ESC to exit" << "\n";
    while (true)
    {
        if (!cap.read(img)) {
            std::cout << "Capture read error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        cv::imshow("CSI Camera", img);
        int keycode = cv::waitKey(10) & 0xff;
        if (keycode == 27) break;
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't open `VieoCapture cap`; how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To use a GStreamer pipeline in a cv::VideoCapture it must end in an appsink. The appsink is a GStreamer element that allows an application (in this case OpenCV) to take buffers out of the pipeline.

Modify your pipeline to look like the following:

```
std::string pipeline = "uridecodebin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! appsink";
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I change pipeline string value to your suggested. buit have another problem like below.
===========
[ WARN:0] global C:\opencv4.2.0\opencv-4.2.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1759) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Secure connection setup failed.
===========
cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline.
===========
cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created.
==========
how can i fix it?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I success play video using this pipeline "videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! autovideoconvert ! appsink". but I still have problem in playing URI video...

Comment: can you set the GST_DEBUG=2 env variable and run your OpenCV app again? That should print a hint of what the error could be